# Peer to peer connection (Wifi Direct) between Raspberry Pis using wlan0 and static ip addresses without a router

Tags: static-ip, p2p

I'm trying to set up a peer to peer connection between 2 raspberry pi 4 model b's with wlan0 and static ip addresses and without the use of a router. This is how my wpa_supplicant.conf file looks

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
update_config=1
country=US

network={
     ssid="1"
     psk="password"
     key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}

ap_scan=1
device_name=raspberrypi
device_type=1-0050F204-1
p2p_go_intent=15
p2p_go_ht40=1
```

I created my static ip in the /etc/network/interfaces file which looks like this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
     address 2.2.2.3
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 0.0.0.0
```

When i enter the interactive mode for wpa_cli for wlan0 it produces a endless output of:

```
CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
```

When i say p2p_find it says OK and when i say p2p_peers it doesn't output anything